# How can I attach derby java db or de-attach from database console [manager]

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

it is possible in java database console to attach
or deattach portable database same as one can do
in oracle or SQL server enterprise manager is there any
function or code to achieve the same in JAVA DB console 
coming along with Netbeans .

Comment: Are you asking if a Derby database is portable across machines?

Comment: Hi Bryan yes is it portable database

Comment: Yes, Derby databases are portable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20933116/does-copy-pasting-apache-derby-db-files-into-another-system-make-it-work-fine